# Is there any solution Like SharePoint in Linux?

Tags: software-rec

We have three server [SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint) , Project Server and CRM and we want to change them and migrate to Linux solutions.

Now we have to change SharePoint by Linux solution ?

we want to have a solution for **collaboration management** and **document management**

Comment: This question is way too general to get useful answers. There are many collaboration management and document management programs out there. I recommend following the [Software Recommendation Stack Exchange guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) — explain what you want (with precise requirements) and why you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alfresco is one I heard about: http://www.unixmen.com/alfresco-an-opensource-alternative-of-microsoft-sharepoint/

Comment: +1 Thanks but i want to know that does exist any checklist or benchmark for comparing them. other question is : office apps like word connect to and integrate easily or not?